# Why does JavaScript to intercept formData that works 'in the wild' (on a web page) not work in a fiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms, jsfiddle

I use a callback function on a submit event to retrieve the formData. It works correctly on a this [test page](https://familyhistoryconferencenwa.org/test-register-2019) on my [web site](https://familyhistoryconferencenwa.org). I was attempting to build a fiddle to use for another question. I discovered that the same code does not work in a fiddle. Instead of the correct formData, it returns a formData with `array.length == 0`.

The code uses jQuery for the document.ready function. jQuery was correctly loaded.

**The JavaScript:**

```
01:    /*  doc.ready w/ traditional callback fn for event listener  */
02:
03:    $(document).ready( function() {
04:      init();
05:
06:    });  // end doc.ready
07:
08:    function init() {
09:      document.addEventListener("submit", processFormData);
10:    }  // end def fn init
11:
12:    functon processFormData(event) {
13:      var formData = new FormData();
14:      event.preventDefault();
15:      formData = $( 'form' ).serializeArray();
16:
17:                console.log('formData : ', formData);
18:
19.    }  //  end def fn processFormDat;
```

With data entered in the live form, **formData returns an array that**, in relevant part, **is this:**

```
3: Object {name: "select-yui_3_nnn ... nnn-field", value: "unsure"}
4: Object {name: "select-yui_3_nnn ... nnn-field", value: "A"}
5: Object {name: "select-yui_3_nnn ... nnn-field", value: "B"}
6: Object {name: "select-yui_3_nnn ... nnn-field", value: "A"}
7: Object {name: "select-yui_3_nnn ... nnn-field", value: "unsure"}
8: Object {name: "select-yui_3_nnn ... nnn-field", value: "C"}
length: 9
```

(The `formData.name` 'yui' attributes are not constant. They are generated dynamically on each page load. They cannot be used to reference the items.)

**In [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alxfyv/2aj5fhwd/73/), the console is this:**

```
formData : Array []
```

`formData.length == 0`.

So, **the Question is why?**

**The HTML:**
My website is built on the Squarespace platform using one of its 'form blocks.' The HTML is incredibly complex. I wouldn't try to reproduce it here.

The HTML in the fiddle is simple. I reproduce it here so that you will not have to click through.

```
01;  <form method="POST">
02:  <div>
03:    <label>First Name
04:      <input type="text" size="25">
05:    </label>
06:  </div>
07:  <div>
08:    <label>Last Name
09:      <input type="text" size="25">
10:    </label>
11:  </div>
12:  </form>
```

```js
console.config({
  maxEntries: Infinity
});

/*  doc.ready w/ traditional callback fn for event listener  */

$(document).ready(function() {
  init();
}); // end doc.ready

function init() {
  document.addEventListener("submit", processFormData);
} // end def fn init

function processFormData(event) {
  var formData = new FormData();
  event.preventDefault();
  formData = $('form').serializeArray();

  console.log('formData : ', formData);

} //  end def fn processFormData
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="testForm" method="post">
  <div>
    <label>First Name
    <input type="text" name="fname"  size="25">
  </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Last Name
    <input type="text" name="lname" size="25">
  </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>email address
    <input type="email" name="email" size="25">
  </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>08:30 Keynote Speaker
    <select name="select0830">
      <option value="">unsure</option>
      <option value="attend">attend</option>
      <option value="not attend">not attend</option>
    </select>
  </label>
    <label>09:00 Classes
    <select name="select0900">
      <option value="">unsure</option>
      <option value="class room A">room A</option>
      <option value="class room B">room B</option>
    </select>
    </label>
    <label>10:30 Classes
    <select name="select1030">
      <option value="">unsure</option>
      <option value="class room A">room A</option>
      <option value="class room B">room B</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit form">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: See https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/: "The .serializeArray() method uses the standard W3C rules for successful controls to determine which elements it should include; in particular the element cannot be disabled and **must contain a name attribute**."

Comment: Also, you need to include a [mcve] in your question. See [ask]. The best way to do that is with the built-in snippet editor. Your current question contains incomplete code with unnecessary line numbers and is missing some elements.

Comment: @Herohtar : Thank you for pointing out the Stack Snippet. I added one to the question. Thanks for the info about the `name` attribute. In the snippet, I added names to the form fields. That solved the problem. It explains too why the js works on my test page. I used the browser's element inspector to see name attributes on each field/ I should have thought to try to find the documentation on `serializeArray()`. As to incomplete code, I believe you are mistaken. The 19 lines of js are all there are in the js in the test page. I can't see any missing elements. Thanks again, ever so much!

Comment: I'm not mistaken about the incomplete code, but I am talking about the HTML, not the JavaScript -- take a look at the original HTML listing that is still in your question here: there is a `<div>` tag at the end that doesn't have a closing tag, it doesn't include any submit button, and the `<form>` is also missing its closing tag.

Comment: @Herohtar Thanks for your persistence. I apologize for the sloppy HTML. Thanks again for your two earlier comments that, when I read them in concert with Nick Parsons answer below, gave me the answer. I marked his as the accepted answer but upvoted your two comments too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with your usage of the method:

```
$('form').serializeArray();
```

[`.serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) will look at the form you gave it and build an array of object's using the `name` field from each form control present within the form. As you said the `name` field is generated dynamically you'll get your result only when they are generated. If the `name` attributes are never generated then you'll never get your data (as they are never generated in your snippet you'll never get your data).

Thus, in order to get `.serializeArray` to work, you need to give your form inputs the `name` attribute.

See working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z32a8h5k/1/)

Also note, there is no need for `new FormData()`. You are overwriting this data with an array returned by `$('form').serializeArray();`

Comment: Thanks so much! Between your answer and @herchtar's comments, I understand. It explains why the code works on the test page on my site. Each form element has a name attribute. They selector names are indeed 'yui' names. But the doc.ready item should take care of that, no? The tags all have name attributes by the time the form is displayed. doc.ready keeps the js from executing until all the HTML elements are in place. I can't _use_  the name attribute in the js, but, in my case at least, I don't need to. Thanks again for the explanation. It's most helpful.

Comment: @alxfyv yeah, you're right. The names attributes should be added to your elements dynamically, and so there is no need to add the name attribute for your site.